# How do i send a script file using mailx to another user on the Host pc on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, vmware, fedora

i'm using fedora and i'm wanting to send a file using mailx to another user on the host PC, how would i go about doing this? i only know how to send to a email address

i'm new to this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i only know how to send to a email address

Then you are nearly there.  Send it to username@localhost where username is his login name.